# WSO2is maven package for OauthTokenIssuerImpl

Tags: maven, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to write a custom JWT access token generator/issuer for WSO2 IS 5.3.0.

as per the post https://medium.com/@hasinthaindrajee/self-contained-access-tokens-with-wso2-identity-server-82111631d5b6 I need to implement a class that extends org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.**OauthTokenIssuerImpl**.

yet when I check out the example implememtation at https://github.com/hasinthaindrajee/SelfContainedAccessTokenGenerator

I find myself missing the class org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.**OauthTokenIssuerImpl**

so, my question: what is the groupId, artifactId and version of the corresponding package? and what is the repository that contains the package?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for the above class is available [here](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/oauth2/token/OauthTokenIssuerImpl.java). You can refer the component's pom.xml [here](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth/pom.xml) for the groupId, artifactId etc.